# Refactor log4j2 properties file

Tags: logging, properties

I have the following `log4j2.properties` file:

```
status = info
name = my-app

# properties
property.name = my-app
property.basePath = log
property.filename = ${basePath}/${name}.log

# console layout
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = console-logger
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c{1}.%M:%L - %msg%n

# rolling layout
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = rolling-file-logger
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${basePath}/${name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c{1}.%M:%L - %msg%n

# rolling policies
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy

# root logger
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRefs = rolling, stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = console-logger
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = rolling-file-logger
```

The main criteria I am aiming for is:

1. Log files to `log/my-app.log`.
2. Rollover log files each minute to `log/my-app-yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm.log`.

The properties file above works for my purposes, but I would like to remove redundancy wherever possible.

A couple questions:

1. Is there a way to use the variable `name = my-app`? I created another variable `property.name`, but not entirely sure that's necessary.
2. Both `console-logger` and `rolling-file-logger` have the same `layout.type` and `layout.pattern`. Is there a simpler way to have both loggers use the same `layout.type` and `layout.pattern` without defining it twice?
3. Any other opportunities for simplifying.